# Is it safe to delete Windows post installation files?

Tags: windows

I have Windows XP installed on the first partition and the second partition is empty. I also have an external hard drive plugged in. I installed Windows Vista on the second partition and now my external hard drive got some odd files that I don't have permission to access. What are those files and is it safe to delete them?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to delete them.  Sometimes you need to take ownership (and then change permissions) before trying to delete them.

Answer (score 4):

Take ownership is explained here: http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/67717-take-ownership-file.html